# Shadowbox crashing QuickTime plugin in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, plugins, quicktime, shadowbox

I'm trying to display videos in a lightbox-type frame when the user clicks the link marked "ASL": 
http://glaclab.linguistics.uconn.edu/BRIEF/BRIEF.php

Although there are a number of issues (listed below for any good samaritans who want to help), my main problem is that whenever I click any of the "ASL" links from Chrome, the lightbox frame loads, but no video plays, and I get the following error: "QuickTime plug-in 7.6.6 has crashed".  This is happening with Chrome 32.0.1700.77 on a Mac running 10.6.  It behaves properly with Firefox and Safari on my Mac, and with Firefox and IE on a Windows 8 PC.

In attempting to test it with Chrome on the Windows 8 PC, I couldn't even get the QuickTime plug-in to install!  It seemed to execute, but then it wasn't listed under Chrome://plugins, and whenever I clicked the "ASL" link, it persistently told me I needed to install the QuickTime plugin.

I'm using the standalone Shadowbox 3.0.3 scripts (no js library), and the videos all play fine if you open them in another tab.  (With Chrome on the PC, the new tab command ends up downloading the files, but they then play fine outside the browser.)

Final comments: if you start working with the link, avoid using the very first link as your testing example; there have been some issues with intermittent functionality with that clip only; all the rest are reliably functional everywhere except Chrome.  Also, some php errors may print to the screen about "undefined index" for a bunch of different POST variables; those aren't set 'cause I've linked you directly to a page that you'd normally get only after submitting a form.  Those are not a concern.

Thanks in advance to whoever is willing to help me figure this out!  I'm also open to alternative proposals- I just want something that's going to let people play these videos no matter what browser they're using.  For my purposes, I also don't need mobile support.

Comment: Update: Chrome still crashes even on a Windows 7 machine with QuickTime plugin 7.7.4.  This is enough to tell me that playing .mov files via shadowbox is not a viable solution if I want full cross-browser compatibility.  The new question is should I ditch .mov, shadowbox, or both?  And what should I use instead?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is related, but for me, what stopped Quicktime from crashing in Chrome, was removing the type:

type="audio/x-wav"

or

type="audio/mpeg"